# understanding the operator<<() from std::cout

Tags: c++

I have written this little code for one of my student coworker, in order to illustrate overloading in c++ :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout.operator<<("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I thought naively I will have two times "Hello World!". But the second line send me an adress. I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) (emphasis mine):

> Character and character string arguments (e.g., of type char or const
> char*) are handled by the **non-member overloads of operator<<**. [...]
> Attempting to output a character string using the member function call syntax will call overload (7) and print the pointer value instead.

So in your case, calling the member `operator<<` will indeed print the pointer value, since `std::cout` does not have an overload for `const char*`.

Instead you can call the free function `operator<<` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";           //prints the string
    std::cout.operator<<("Hello World!");  //prints the pointer value
    operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World!"); //prints the string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ah yes ! I didn't see this note. Thank you

Comment: So, _some_ of the operator functions are member functions, and some free functions? ...why?

Answer (score 3):

If an operator is a member function then

```
object operator other_operand
```

is equivalent to

```
object.operator(other_operand)
```

However, if the operator is not a member then it is rather

```
operator(object,other_operand)
```

Here you can find the list of overloads of `<<` that are members https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

And here the list of overloads that are non members https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

Note that the `operator<<` for `char*` is not a member! But there is a member `operator<<` for `void*` that can print the value of a pointer of any type.